# Stop looking for user input with 'bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)'

Tags: go, input, channel

New to golang and programming in general. I am currently writing a small quiz program for a learning task and ran into a snag that the tutorial does not address because I have features not included on the tutorial.

*Code is included below*:

```
func runQuestions(randomize bool) int {
tempqSlice := qSlice //Create temporary set of questions (Don't touch original)
if randomize { //If user has chosen to randomize the question order
    tempqSlice = shuffle(tempqSlice) //Randomize
}

var runningscore int

userinputchan := make(chan string) //Create return channel for user input
go getInput(userinputchan) //Constantly wait for user input

for num, question := range tempqSlice { //Iterate over each question
    fmt.Printf("Question %v:\t%v\n\t", num+1, question.GetQuestion())
    select {
    case <-time.After(5 * time.Second): //
        fmt.Println("-time up! next question-")
        continue
    case input := <-userinputchan:
        if question.GetAnswer() == input { //If the answer is correct
            runningscore++
            continue //Continue to next question
        }
    }

}
return runningscore
```

}

```
func getInput(returnchan chan<- string) {
for {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin) //Create reader
    input, _ := reader.ReadString('\n') //Read from
    returnchan <- strings.TrimSpace(input) //Trim the input and send it
}
```

}

Because the specification of the problem requires each question to have a timelimit, I have set a 'endless for loop go routine' running that waits for user input and then sends it when it is given. My problem is simple: I would like to stop the reader looking for input once the quiz is over but since the 'reader.ReadString('/n')' is already awaiting input, I'm not sure how.

Comment: You can't. Just leave it until the program exits.

Comment: For input with different parts of the program, would I therefore simply move the 'Input loop' closer to the top of the program and pass its channel to any other function wanting input?

Comment: Create a case based on the amount of questions answered against the length of the questions. `case amountOfQuestionsAnswered == len(questions): exit`

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to stop the reader looking for input once the quiz is over

While the reader is looking for input, you can use a goroutine that runs in its background to check whether the quiz timer is expired.

Suppose your timer for quiz is 30 seconds. Pass the timer to the goroutine `getInput`and check for the timer expiry.

```
var runningscore int
userinputchan := make(chan string) //Create return channel for user input
myTime := flag.Int("timer", 30, "time to complete the quiz")
timer := startTimer(myTime)
go getInput(userinputchan, timer)
```

```
func startTimer(myTime *int) *time.Timer {
    return time.NewTimer(time.Duration(*myTime) * time.Second)
}

func getInput(returnchan chan<- string, timer *time.Timer) {
    for {
        reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)    //Create reader
        go checkTime(timer)                    
        input, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')    //Read from
        returnchan <- strings.TrimSpace(input) //Trim the input and send it
    }
}

func checkTime(timer *time.Timer) {
    <-timer.C
    fmt.Println("\nYour quiz is over!!!")
    // print the final score
    os.Exit(1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this out of the box, however you can make a workaround by reading character by character from `stdin`, buffering the inputs and only sending the buffered data when the user hits `Enter`.

Unfortunately, there is there is no standard package for reading character by character, I will be using `github.com/eiannone/keyboard`. (You can get it by `go get -u github.com/eiannone/keyboard`).

The following class will be your input system. You can instantiate it by calling `NewInput(yourResultChannel)`. This will start reading from `stdin` character by character and buffers them into `buf`. Once `Enter` (`char == 0`) is hit, it sends the contents of the buffer to the resultChannel end resets the buffer.

```
type Input struct {
    lock     sync.Mutex
    buf      []rune
    resultCh chan string
}

func NewInput(resultCh chan string) *Input {
    i := &Input{
        resultCh: resultCh,
    }

    go i.readStdin()
    return i
}

func (i *Input) ResetBuffer() {
    i.lock.Lock()
    defer i.lock.Unlock()

    i.resetBuffer()
}

func (i *Input) readStdin() {
    for {
        char, _, err := keyboard.GetSingleKey()
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("%s", string(char))

        i.lock.Lock()
        if char == 0 {
            i.resultCh <- strings.TrimSpace(string(i.buf))
            i.resetBuffer()
        } else {
            i.buf = append(i.buf, char)
        }
        i.lock.Unlock()
    }
}

func (i *Input) resetBuffer() {
    i.buf = []rune{}
}
```

Your only remaining job is to create an instance of the Input class at the point where you were previously starting your `getInput()` goroutine.

```
userinputchan := make(chan string) //Create return channel for user input
input := NewInput(userinputchan)
```

and reset the buffer when the question times out so that the previous garbage input won't be part of the new question's answer. In the select statement:

```
case <-time.After(5 * time.Second):
    fmt.Println("-time up! next question-")
    input.ResetBuffer()
    continue
```

Full code: https://play.golang.org/p/-IXVvY9dOZO